# Printing internal representation of a Coq term

Tags: ocaml, coq

How to print the internal OCaml representation of a term in Coq (exposing the data constructors like Lambda, App, Rel, etc... )?

Is there any equivalent of derived `show`, as in Haskell, in OCaml?

Comment: The language you refer to is written “OCaml”. Note the capitalization. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.caml/F4Q_RzT1t1Q

Answer (score 0):

You can print the body of any Coq term using the vernacular command `Show`. There is a lot of notations in Coq that can hide some terms, so you can also deactivate the notations using CoqIDE's menu, or using the command `Set Printing All.` in coqtop/ProofGeneral, prior to calling `Show`.

However this will expose the term in the Coq language, not it's OCaml encoding. If you want the underlying Ocaml representation, I guess you'll have to hack a bit Coq's code. I am not aware of any such command as for today.

For the `show` type class, I don't think there is one in the std, by I might mistaken.